# A stack of strings

Tags: c, string, stack

I'm trying to implement a stack which contains strings and I think I'm pretty close right now
but I don't really know why it's not working

edit:
Something like that? Am I close now?

```
int pop(char **x)
{
    if (isEmpty())
        return 0;
    else
    {
        struct Node *temp = head;
        *x = head->wyraz;
        head = head->next;
        free(temp);
        return 1;
    }
}


int main()
{
char buf[255];
char *str;
while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin) != 0 && buf[0] != '\n')
{   

    push(buf); 
}



while (pop(&str) != 0)
{
    printf("%s\n", str);
    free(str);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want code review, there's another discussion on Stack Exchange for that purpose. If you have a specific problem, explain what it is.

Comment: The answers you received are good but next time you should tell us what 'not working' means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `insert()` function, you don't make a copy of the string, so when the next line is read, it will overwrite the previous string.  Thus, all items in the stack will end up with the same data as the last line read.  You'll need to allocate memory for the string and copy the input to the allocated memory.  Remember to allow for the trailing null, and also the fact that `fgets()` keeps the newline on data that is read.

Your test using the zeroth element of the array pointed at by the return from `fgets()` will crash on EOF.  The loop condition should be:

```
while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin) != 0 && buf[0] != '\n')
{
    …
```

You should test that all the values you push onto the stack are printed by repeatedly popping data until there's nothing left.  Remember to free the data correctly.

Your `pop()` code has problems.  You should be getting a warning from your compiler about a pointer to integer conversion.  You might need to use:

```
int pop(char **x)
{
    if (isEmpty())
        return 0;
    else
    {
        struct Node *temp = head;
        *x = head->wyraz;
        head = head->next;
        free(temp);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

You'd have to use it like:

```
char *str;

while (pop(&str) != 0)
{
    printf("[%s]\n", str);
    free(str);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First major problem that I see is that you simply store the *pointer* into the stack and that's always set to `buf` and continuously being overwritten.

You should `strdup` the string to ensure each node gets a unique buffer (and remember to `free` it at some point after you've popped it).

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues:

- You are always using the same string buffer `buf` to do the `insert`
- Your `pop` function is a little confused. I think you're trying to return a pointer to the string that is on the top of the stack, in which case you need to pass a `char **x` not a `char *x`. Then call it with a pointer, `pop(&p)`. But it's hard to tell what your intention is there.

I'd name `insert` as `push` by the way, if you want to maintain the stack paradigm.